# How to read Json String which is coming in Key-Value format?

Tags: jquery, json, key-value

I am calling `getTags` web-method which returns hash-table in JSON format.
following is return value which is formatted by

```
jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response))
```

and assigned to variable  `jsonObj`

I want read Key and Its value .How can I do this?

```
var jsonObj = {"getTags":[
                 {"Key":"TagID","Value":2},
                 {"Key":3,"Value":"Best College"}
                 ]
               }
```

Comment: read this : http://www.mooforum.net/solutions12/json-key-value-output-t2265.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve key and value from JSON String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927170/how-to-retrieve-key-and-value-from-json-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var jsonObj = {"getTags":[{"Key":"TagID","Value":2},{"Key":3,"Value":"Best College"}]}
        for ( var i =0 ; i

Answer (score 0):

You made json bit complex by using "Keys" and "value" again as keys. Ideal JSON should be as given below:

```
var jsonObj ={
        "getTags": {
            "3": "Best College",
            "TagID": 2
        }
    }
```

Use below jquery to process this object:

```
var items=[];
 $.each(jsonObj, function(key, val) {
    // you can do whatever you want with key value pair.
    items.push(val);
  });
console.log(items); // items contains   ["Best College",2]
```

More help on [jQuery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)